# Is there an addon that shows the NumPad on the screen when entering numbers like object size in Blender?

Tags: add-on

[image]

I want to show the NumPad on the screen like this image when I enter a number such as object size. (I made the NumPad in this image by myself using Python's Tkinter, but it doesn't work well yet due to my lack of ability.)

I want the NumPad to appear automatically when I enter the number input mode (when I click on the number text box), not after I press some button by myself.

Is there any add-on or extension that can do this?

Comment: Just for the sake of intrest, can you send a link of your python code? (If it is ok with you)

Comment: Also out of interest, why do you want to do this? And would an onscreen keyboard help?

Comment: To Leander's Comment: Onscreen Keyboard in [Mac](https://www.wikihow.com/Enable-the-Onscreen-Keyboard-on-a-Mac), [Windows](https://www.howtogeek.com/240288/how-to-use-the-on-screen-keyboard-on-windows-7-8-and-10/) and [Linux](https://www.xmodulo.com/onscreen-virtual-keyboard-linux.html)